# Javascript replace linktext with title

Tags: javascript, href, rename, greasemonkey

I regularly visit a website with a lot of links of the following format:

```
<a href="SomeURL" title="SomeTitle" id="SomeID">SomeText</a>
```

Sadly the part SomeText is useless in most cases and I want to replace it with SomeTitle. Therefor I tried my luck with a Greasemonkey-Script (inject Javascript to a webpage). I want to modify all Links on the page.

My goal is this:

```
<a href="SomeURL" title="SomeTitle" id="SomeID">SomeTitle</a>
```

I already tried my luck, but since I'm not familiar with javascript this is all I got so far, of course it did not work...

```
document.links.innerHTML = document.links.title
```

I hope somebody can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Thanks for the fast replies, I add a comment to each answer with a feedback, if it solves the problem or not.

Its just strange, that none of these solution have a 100% success-rate. Sometimes I have to reload the page 2-3 times to get the code working. (Not a cache-problem, I swear)
I though it maybe have to load the page fully to work, but when I add a timeout before running the code it only works on a few divs and not the entire page.
This is just additional information, no further help is needed. Im fine, if I have to reload the page sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the document loads:

```
var theLink = document.getElementById('SomeID');
theLink.innerHTML = theLink.getAttribute('title');
```

Or in your case all links:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
[].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute('title') || element.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: The code you add with your edit does exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');  // get all the links.
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    // It will replace text only if `title` is present.
    link.innerText = link.getAttribute('title') || link.innerText;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me, thanks for your effort anyway

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
var i, links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i in links) { 
    var title = links[i].title;
    if(title) {
        links[i].innerHTML = title;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $("a[title]").length; i++) {
     $("a[title]:eq("+i+")").text($("a[title]:eq("+i+")").attr("title"));
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work, but I decided to use a solution without jQuery